# C# MVC multiple loading javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

everyone.
I am using NET Framework 4.8.1.
I'm having a problem when I try to reload a view, it's like it doesn't delete my javascript and going to reload it sends all the constants to me in error.

I attach the code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="row bg-dark">
    <div class="col-2" style="margin-top: 1%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Menu</h2>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                    <li>
                        <a onclick="LoadComponents()" id="btnDashboard" class="nav-link text-white active">
                            Dashboard
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="btnNotification" class="nav-link text-white position-relative">
                            Notification <span id="spanCount" style="color: red;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                            Logout
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-10" style="margin-top: 1%;" id="divLoadComponent">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Js:

```
function LoadComponents(){        
    $('#divLoadComponent').empty()

    var url = '@Url.Action("Accounts", "Home")'
    $('#divLoadComponent').load(url)
}
```

It behaves as if the script is not deleted with `$('#divLoadComponent').empty()` and as a result I reload all the html with the script each time and the constants fail, in addition to the fact that the alerts are repeated for each time I click on "Dashboard".

Comment: If there are `<script>` tags in the content you `.load()` into that element, then calling `.empty()` will not undo the effects the script had when jQuery ran it the first time the content was loaded.

Comment: @Pointy Exactly! What do you recommend I do?

Comment: Well, seems like the best thing to do is avoid having `<script>` tags in content you're going to load with jQuery that way. You can load the script directly once, and then load only the content as many times as you want.  Or, you could load the content differently: I think that behavior is only performed by jQuery when you use `.load()`, so if you use `.ajax()` directly you can stuff the content in your container with `.html()` (which will *not* run the scripts).

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I change the logic of my js file and now it's work.